# ReCaptcha with Laravel 5 form class not found error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to use [greggilbert/recaptcha](https://github.com/greggilbert/recaptcha) with my contact form and I'm getting `Class 'Recaptcha' not found`.

I added `Greggilbert\Recaptcha\RecaptchaServiceProvider::class,` to providers and `'Recaptcha' => Greggilbert\Recaptcha\Facades\Recaptcha::class,` to aliases in app.php after requiring the package in composer.json then updating like the readme says.

Here is my contact form:

```
<form id="contact" method="post" class="form" role="form">

  @if(Session::has('errors'))
   <div class="alert alert-warning">
    @foreach(Session::get('errors')->all() as $error_message)
     <p>{{ $error_message }}</p>
    @endforeach
   </div>
  @endif

  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 form-group">
    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}" />
    <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text"autofocus="">
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 form-group">
    <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="body" placeholder="Body" rows="5"></textarea>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 form-group">
     {!! Recaptcha::render() !!}
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit">Submit</button>
   </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by running `php artisan config:clear` then re-running `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Greggilbert\Recaptcha\RecaptchaServiceProvider"`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you already find a solution, but to the next one who will have the same problem, always remember to run `composer dump-autoload`, and, in this case, when having problems with configuration cache, run the command `php artisan config:clear`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a backslash (`\`) before the class:

```
{!! \Recaptcha::render() !!}
```

This makes sure you are in the root namespace, where the providers are created.

Comment: No dice, still got the same error. I had also tried using the [anhskohbo/no-captcha](https://github.com/anhskohbo/no-captcha) package the other day and had almost exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried `php artisan config:clear` first, but only

```
php artisan clear-compiled
```

worked for me.